# I Would Like To Open Files in Different Tabs in the Same Window Using Xcode 5

Tags: macos, xcode, tabs

I'm new to using Xcode.  When I started using Xcode a couple of weeks ago I had a file list to the left and had three tabs open for different files.  I'm not sure if that was a default setting or not.

This morning there was an update to iTunes.  I could not update it without closing Xcode.  Before if I opened a new tab it would open the same file that was in the other tab.  All I had to do was open a new file and it would open in the active tab.  Now when I open files they open in a new window.

I have done online searches but they are for previous versions of Xcode.

How do I set up my preferences where a file list displays to the left as before and open files in new tabs instead of new windows?

Comment: Do You open file by double or single click? Double click opens file in new window/tab (depending on prefs), single click opens it in active tab.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Left column in Xcode is called **Navigator**. You can show/hide it with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (Zero), or in the upper right window corner, see image:
 [image]

In the **Navigator** there are dfferent tabs (Project Navigator, Symbols Navigator etc.). To see list of files in Your project You need to select **Project Navigator** or press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

To open file in current tab, single click on it in Navigator. If You double click the file, it would open in new window/tab. You can change the behaviour of double click in `Preferences...` -> `Navigation` -> `Double Click Navigation`.